# Highlight selected value in drop down in angularjs

Tags: html, css, angularjs, ng-options

I would like to display the selected value in the drop down in angularjs.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <script
 src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"> 
  </script>
<body>
  <div><select class="form-control" size="30" style=" 
        height:100px;width:100px" ng-model="value" ng-options="c.name for c 
        in customers track by c.id" ng-change="onChange">
       <option value="" selected hidden />
        </select></div>
</body>
</html>
```

By doing the above way it doesn't highlight the selected value.If I change the `ng-options` as `ng-options="c.id as c.name for c in customers track by c.id"`. In the value I see `id` instead of `name`.

Comment: I updated the question in order to format the code parts properly, but, please, consider editing the post again in order to provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) if possible. I don't even see a valid angular application here (`ng-app`?, `ng-controller`?, etc). This way, it's more likely volunteers on SO can help you.

Comment: what does your `value` and `customers` contain, can you those?

Comment: Hi Sravan customers is an array of objects with the below format:[{"name":"x","id":1},{"name":"y","id":2}].So the value should contain name of the customer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing ng-selected attribute, add attribute ng-selected="value" to your select element. And you don't need the option element, and also the track by statement needs to be removed.

```
<select class="form-control" size="30" style=" height:100px;width:100px" 
       ng-model="value" ng-selected="value" 
       ng-options="c.id as c.name for c in customers">
</select>
```

Comment: Hi Khal i tried with ng-selected but it didnot work.I edited my code if there is a ng-change in select then wont the value will be highlighted?If  i use ng-options="c.id as c.name for c in customers track by c.id" in my value i get id instead of name which is not what i wanted.

Comment: The problem is because of track by statement. According to angular documentation it gets tricky if you try to use both 'as' and 'track by' statements in ng-options. For more detailed information refer to https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions . In your case removing track by statement should make it work. I have also edited the answer above to reflect the same.

Comment: Khal ng-options="c.id as c.name for c in customers" gives me id but i want name.Even though i removed track by it still didnot work for me.

Comment: I can only think of something wrong with your customers object, are you sure it is in the form {name:'xxx', id:xxx} ? Below is the link to a working example in plunker https://plnkr.co/edit/V3t6y3LLRF1lz2eRtmXp

Comment: Khal i edited the plunkr with my JSON data and here is the link:https://plnkr.co/edit/yt5hdMnFu7FvSGN4JYB8?p=preview

Comment: You are not assigning customer object to scope properly, use = for assignment not :  Your code: $scope.customers:{dept:[10,20],products:['X01','YO2'],info:[{name:'ABC',id:1},{name:'LMN',id:2}]}   It should be: $scope.customers={dept:[10,20],products:['X01','YO2'],info:[{name:'ABC',id:1},{name:'LMN',id:2}]} 
  here is the link to working solution https://plnkr.co/edit/pzlsskPTcix9HA4SAzGu?p=preview